# With a Collection of File, get a getPath() relate to specific folder

Tags: java, file, pdf, path, apache-commons

i'm using

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
```

for get all the filed PDF contained in a specified folder (and relative subfolders)

Here a simple code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collection;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.TrueFileFilter;

public class FileFilterTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File ROOT_DIR = new File("C:\\PDF_Folder");

        Collection<File> PDF_FILES = FileUtils.listFiles(ROOT_DIR, new IOFileFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File file)
            {
                return file.getName().endsWith(".pdf");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
            {
                return name.endsWith(".pdf");
            }
        }, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);

        for(File pdf : PDF_FILES)
        {
            System.out.println(pdf.getPath());
        }
    }
}
```

the getPath() method returns the Absolute Path like this

```
C:\PDF_Folder\SomeFolder\AnotherFolder\A\20120430_TT006059__0000039.pdf
C:\PDF_Folder\Folder1\A\20120430_TT006060__000003A.pdf
C:\PDF_Folder\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\B\20120430_TT006071__000003B.pdf
C:\PDF_Folder\Folder4\20120430_TT006125__000003C.pdf
```

Is there a way to get only the path related to the provided Root Folder?

```
SomeFolder\AnotherFolder\A\20120430_TT006059__0000039.pdf
Folder1\A\20120430_TT006060__000003A.pdf
Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\B\20120430_TT006071__000003B.pdf
Folder4\20120430_TT006125__000003C.pdf
```

EDIT: Here the solution created by code of jsn

```
for(File pdf : PDF_FILES)
{
    URI rootURI = ROOT_DIR.toURI();
    URI fileURI = pdf.toURI();

    URI relativeURI = rootURI.relativize(fileURI);
    String relativePath = relativeURI.getPath();

    System.out.println(relativePath);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
String relPath = new File(".").toURI().relativize(pdf.toURI()).getPath();
System.out.println(relPath);
```

Tested, this works.

Comment: @DevlingMaster Actually, there is duplicate code in there, I edited.

Comment: I've added my final code to the main question based on your tips. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to simply 'subtract' the root path from the filename:

```
pdf.getPath().substring(ROOT_DIR.getPath().length() + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you something like this as well:

```
for(File pdf : PDF_FILES)
{
        System.out.println(pdf.getParentFile().getName()
                             + System.getProperty("file.separator")
                             + pdf.getName());
}
```

Comment: My mistake indeed, but i forgot to clarify that there is a not defined number of subdirectories to search in. The path might be long different from each other (I've edited the main post to explain better). The _getParentFile().getName()_ method give me only the last folder name

Comment: @DevilingMaster: Well in that case Reimeus answer is what you are looking for :)

Comment: @Sujay: I'll use jsn solution, it's working (I've added the final code to main post)